# Records not getting inserted in ascending order

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a strange problem. I have a HTML page with PHP code which inserts data to a MySQL database. The data gets saved to the DB without any errors but in an incorrect order.

Here's a screenshot. The table on the right side displays the existing records. The first 2 records are shown correctly.
[image]
But when I save more records, it displays like this.
[image]
[image]

Even in the MySQL table, the records are inserted that way.

[image]

I'm not sure where exactly the problem is so I've shown the whole code for the page below. I've commented what each code block does. Please comment if you need me to clarify something.

The **Location ID** is an auto-generated code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function SelectAll(source)
{   //The code for the 'Select All' checkbox
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i in checkboxes)
    {
        if(checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//Database connection initialization
require_once("db_handler.php");

$conn = iniCon();
$db = selectDB($conn);

/* Generating the new Location ID */
$query = "SELECT LID FROM locations ORDER BY LID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$last_id = $row['LID'];

$id_letter = substr($last_id, 0, 1);
$id_num = substr($last_id, 1) + 1;
$id_num = str_pad($id_num, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
//$id_num = sprintf("%03d", $id_num);
$new_id = $id_letter . $id_num;

/* Displaying the exsisting locations */        
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<! The table which displays the existing records >
<div id="display">
<b>Locations</b><br/><br/>
<form name="displayLocs" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Location ID</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th><i>Delete</i></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><? echo $row["LID"]; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><? echo $row["Code"]; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["Location"]; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row["LID"]; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>

<br/>
    <div id="buttons2">
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="SelectAll(this)" />Select All <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="deletebtn" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<! New record saving area >
<b id="loc_caption_1">Enter a new location</b>
<div id="loca">
    <form name="locForm" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
        <table width="300" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Location ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lid" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $new_id; ?>" style="text-align:right" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="code" style="text-align:right" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="loc" style="text-align:right" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input type="submit" value="Save" name="savebtn" />
</div>
    </form>

<?php
//Saving record
if(isset($_POST["savebtn"]))
{
    $id = $_POST["lid"];
    $code = $_POST["code"];
    $location = $_POST["loc"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO locations(LID, Code, Location) VALUES('$id', '$code', '$location')";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

    if (!$result)
    {
        die("Error " . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br/><br/>";
        echo "<strong>1 record added successfully!</strong>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=locations.php\">";
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
}

//Deleting selected records
if(isset($_POST["deletebtn"]))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $del_id = $_POST["checkbox"][$i];
        $query = "DELETE FROM locations WHERE LID = '$del_id' ";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    }

    if (!$result)
    {
        die("Error " . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=locations.php\">";
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is causing this and how to rectify it.

Thank you.

Comment: Add an ORDER BY clause in your SELECT statement?

Comment: Records are not inserted in any order - they simply exist. Order is applied in a query. Also, the way you're generating the Location ID is wrong. You should use an auto increment column instead of querying for the last record.

Comment: You cannot guarantee the order of insertion of records. The order of your data in the table *doesn't matter*! If you want something ordered in output, simply stick an ORDER BY clause in your corresponding SELECT statement.

Comment: I see. I was in doubt because this only started to occur when I implemented this auto-generation for the ID. Before that it was fine even in the database table. Now I get it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The records in the database are stored in the database in no particular order (well, there's some order to it, but it's up to the engine to determine it).  If you want to get the results in a particular order, then you need to explicitly specify it when querying the data.  In your case, make this change:

```
/* Displaying the exsisting locations */        
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY lid";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
```

Comment: I see. I was in doubt because this only started to occur when I implemented this auto-generation for the ID. Before that it was fine even in the database table. Now I understand. Adding the `ORDER BY` clause solved the issue with displaying. Thank you.